# add Class by passing an array

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have this directive, that add 'selectedAnswer' class to all the divs that I click on. I want to add the same class if I pass an array of index `[1,2,4]` from the component.

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[activeOnClick]',
  // Optionally replace this both with properties marked 
  // with @HostBinding and @HostListener decorators
  host: {
    '[class.selectedAnswer]': 'clicked',
    '(click)': '_toggle()'
  }
})
export class ActiveOnClickDirective {
   @Input('activeOnClick')
   clicked = false;

   _toggle(){
     console.log('clicked');
      this.clicked= !this.clicked;
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<div activeOnClick *ngFor="let opt of options; let i=index"
 (click)="answerSelectedMultiple(i)"
```

If a key in opt contains an array like `[1,2,4]`, the indexes 1,2,4 should have selectedAnswer class.

Comment: where is the element that you want to add the `ngClass` in? Also, how are you passing the array from component and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

As I understand your question right, by clicking on the `div` element the `selectedAnswer` class should be added to `div` element. Additionally it should be possible to preselect some of these options.

See example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-question-48238847).

I added a `defaults` array to the `AppComponent` class which defines the preselected options. In your case 1 and 4;

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  defaults = [1,4];
  options = [1,2,3,4];
}
```

This array is bound to the new new input `default` in your directive.

app.component.html

```
<section>
  <div [activeOnClick]="opt" [defaults]="defaults" *ngFor="let opt of options; let i=index">{{opt}}
 clicked me to toggle</div>
</section>
```

Your directive now has all information to determine if the option should be preselected. This check is done in the `ngOnInit` method.

active-on-click.directive.ts

```
export class ActiveOnClickDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() defaults: number[];
  @Input('activeOnClick') key: number;
  clicked = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("opt", this.defaults);

    if(this.defaults.some(x => x === this.key)){
      this.clicked=true;
    }
  }

  _toggle(){
    console.log('clicked');
    this.clicked= !this.clicked;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my code is working now. But I want to auto add the selectedAnswer class to some options if I pass an array like [1,4]. So the option 1 and 4 should have selectedAnswer without clicking on the options. https://so-question-48238847-ggv23j.stackblitz.io